# Jquery - Multiple slideshows on one page using radios

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get more than one slideshow onto a page. I have to use radios as the trigger. I can't get both to display at the same time, one turns the other off!
Please see this [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/designbrand/nhctucg6/30/)

```
var current = '';
$('[name="first_inputs"]').change(function() {
if(current.length) 
$('#' + current).slideUp();
current = $(this).val();
$('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown();
});

var current = '';
$('[name="second_inputs"]').change(function() {
if(current.length) 
$('#' + current).slideUp();
current = $(this).val();
$('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown();
});
```

I have named them differently and the code asks for them by name - why can't I get both to display? (Sorry, I'm just starting out with this stuff.)

Thank you
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were defining two variables with the same name, which caused the variable to interfere with each other.  Renaming them fixes it.

https://jsfiddle.net/nhctucg6/32/

```
var currentFirst = '';
$('[name="first_inputs"]').change(function() {
    if(currentFirst.length) 
        $('#' + currentFirst).slideUp();
    currentFirst = $(this).val();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown();
});

var currentSecond = '';
$('[name="second_inputs"]').change(function() {
    if(currentSecond.length) 
        $('#' + currentSecond).slideUp();
    currentSecond = $(this).val();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown();
});
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you James - I really appreciated your fast answer. I've got a bit more reading to do!